# Is there any way to save breakpoints in IntelliJ and restore later?

Tags: intellij-idea

Can I define a set of breakpoints, and save this definition in IntelliJ and restore later on?

Like I have breakpoints at line `40` and `50` for `Class A`. Can I save them, and later restore in any way?

Comment: Keep a backup of workspace.xml in .idea directory. It contains bookmarks and breakpoints.(Checked for intellij idea 2017.3)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot save/restore breakpoints in IntelliJ, but if you want to work with different "groups" of breakpoints in different situations without having to enable/disable or delete them one by one, you can do that in the current version (IDEA 2016.3.1).

You can create named groups of breakpoints and enable/disable them as a group with a single click.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/working-with-groups-of-breakpoints.html

Comment: This is helpful, but for those reading please consider viewing @komelgman's answer. They have described the location of the XML document that contains the save state of your line breakpoints that I will assume can be cut and pasted into different `.idea/workspace.xml` files. As code and class name changes you will need to keep track of this accordingly in the XML.

Answer (score 40):

You can find all breakpoints in `project-dir/.idea/workspace.xml -> <component name="DebuggerManager">`. You can save their manually.

Comment: In case I need this for the future

sed -n '/DebuggerManager/,/component>/p' workspace.xml  > ~/Desktop/breakpoints.xml

Comment: Is there a difference between `<component name="XDebuggerManager">` and `<component name="DebuggerManager">` ?

Answer (score 14):

This feature is currently not available (not even in Intellij Cardea EAP).

However, there is an IDEA feature request up for this: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-15540.

Want to up-vote the feature request ?

Answer (score 2):

On Android studio you can select multiple break points -> Right click -> Move to group -> new breakpoint group.

After this you can enable/disable entire group just like importing previously saved breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

In ver14  component name is `XDebuggerManager`.

You must be careful about the breakpoint url, especially the path must have variable `$PROJECT_DIR$`.

Answer (score 1):

Since year 2021 you can do it by IDEA plugin [Breakpoint Manager](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17393-breakpoint-manager).